# A link is showing up on the site but I can't find it inside the html. How is that possible and how can I fix it?

Tags: html, css

My client's site (http://mannbilly.com/) is live and he noticed that at the bottom all the last items on his Work section are one link to (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ztm7YkLElI). I did a `Ctrl+F` when I couldn't find out how and it found one result BUT in Chrome inspect it is next to every item that is linking to that video.

```html
<h4 class="section-title">VOICEOVER/SINGING</h4>
<div class="item">Hasbro Toys Commercial (2016)</div>
<div class="item"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uV9s5Ggy3Hk">Scottdw</div>
<div class="item"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ztm7YkLElI">Devinsupertramp</div>
<div class="item">Operatic training – Gary Aldrich (3 months)</div>
<div class="item">Barbershop Choir – Bill Weiser (2 months)</div>
<h4 class="section-title">THEATER</h4>
<div class="item">‘A Christmas Carol’ – Young Ebenezer/Ensemble/Ghost of Christmas Present (understudy)</div>
<div class="item">Adam Cates – Tony Award for “A Gentleman’s Guide To Love and Murder”</div>
<div class="item">University of Nevada Reno</div>
</section>
```

My question is first how is that possible and then how can I fix it?

Please and thanks for any insight or help. I'm stuck and haven't had any luck with Google, developer friends, or reference books I have.

Answer (score 8):

This link/`a` tag is unclosed, so it's putting all of the HTML that comes after it in the link.

```
<div class="item"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ztm7YkLElI">Devinsupertramp</div>
```

Needs to be

```
<div class="item"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ztm7YkLElI">Devinsupertramp</a></div>
```